# Логирования и блокировка файла

Tags: безопасность, c++, многопоточность, логирование

Есть n-ое число потоков (boost/thread.hpp). Каждый с которых записывает, что-то в один файл.

Грубо говоря, это некое логирования: если в потоке происходит ошибка, то она записывается в файл. 
Вопросы:

1. Может ли возникнуть ситуация когда поток не сможет записать лог? Скорее всего да. Как в этом случае быть?
2. Нужно ли блокировать файл на время записи в него? и как это можно сделать блокировку? И как тогда cделать постоянное логирования (тоесть: если к файлу нет доступа, то лог идет в никуда)?

Comment: Используй mutex или семафор или файловые блокировки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Может ли возникнуть ситуация когда поток не сможет записать лог?

да, например, закончиться место на диске. Или любой другой ресурс. Может винт прекратить работу.

> Как в этом случаи быть?

Все зависит от важности приложения. Если это лабораторная работа, то достаточно будет просто завершить работу. Если это кардиостимулятор, то перестать писать в лог, поддерживать дальше работу (на минимальном рабочем уровне) и сигналить, что бы пришел доктор-мастер по ремонту.

В некоторых случаях можно отправить сообщения по сети, попытаться записать в системный лог, записать на специально подготовленную и вставленную флешку. Но если у Вас операционная система разваливается, то, возмножно, ценность записанного лога уже не имеет смысла (он может быть испорчен).

> Нужно ли блокировать файл на время записи в него?

да, потому как файловая система не атомарная.

> и как это можно сделать блокировку?

используйте любые доступные средства синхронизации - mutex, semaphore, critical section (хотя они в многих случаях внутри делаются на mutex'ах).

> И как тогда cделать постоянное логирования (тоесть: если к файлу нет доступа, то лог идет в никуда)?

Можно писать лог в буфер в памяти и время от времени его сбрасывать на диск. Если сообщение с уровнем ERROR - то пытаемся писать сразу, если оно с уровнем info - то можно и проигнорировать.

Не нужно боятся, что часть сообщений будет утеряна, если приложение "упадет". Просто настройте сброс дампа (в линуксах - корки). В этом случае дамп можно будет открыть и посмотреть буфер.

Я, к примеру, под этот буфер выделял несколько мегабайт и писал сообщения заведомо известным размером. Это давало возможность использовать атомарные операции (ведь тому, кто пишет сообщение, нужно лишь пометить строку, а потом можно медленно в нее копировать.). Для того, что бы не блокировать потоки, пока буфер будет сбрасываться на диск - заводиться ещё один-два буфера и циклически меняются. В само начало буфера записывается какая-нибудь уникальная последовательность. Когда исследуется дамп памяти, эти буфера очень легко находятся и извлекаются.

Если все буфера оказались заняты, значит скорее всего либо маленькие буфера (или много сообщений) или диск не успевает писать (или вообще не пишет). В этом случае можно даже упасть - дамп скорее всего будет (хотя если место завершилось на диске, то...).

В любом случае поищите готовые логгеры, возможно они решат все Ваши проблемы и страхи.

Comment: @KoVadim, для \*nix

       Нужно ли блокировать файл на время записи в него?

==
    да, потому как файловая система не атомарная.

Если локальный (не NFS) файл открыт с O_APPEND (то же `fopen(..., "a")`) то данные *каждого `write()`* атомарно  пишутся в конец файла.

Естественно, для `FILE *` так можно записать не более, чем размер буфера FILE.

Comment: Понятно, что в каждом конкретном случае есть свои особенности. И что бы не заморачиваться с этим всем, лучше использовать сторонний готовый логер. И если только он не подходит, то брать и допиливать напильничком.

Comment: @avp @KoVadim если я правильно понимаю, то если я открываю файл на добавления через fopen(), то блокировка не нужна? а что если я открываю файл на добавления через fstream? (для Windows)

Comment: правильный ответ "далеко не факт" - читаем стандарт (выделенное - мое)

27.1.3 Thread safety [iostreams.thread-safety]

Concurrent access to a stream object [string.streams, file.streams], stream buffer object [stream.buffers], or C Library stream [c.files] **by multiple threads** may result in a **data race** [intro.multithread] unless otherwise specified [iostream.objects]. [Note: Data races result in undefined behavior [intro.multithread].

То есть - если только разработчики библиотеки не решили сделать потокобезопасным, то не будет. Стандарт не требует.

Comment: В GNU [можно](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-Threads.html).

Только `fflush()` (и fsync() если боитесь лог потерять) вызывать не забывайте.

Однако, учтите -- fsync может сильно затормозить программу.

Comment: @avp @KoVadim спасибо.